# What is upper and lower bound in a uniform distribution?

Tags: distribution

If I have to use a Uniform Distribution in a simulation what do you mean by lower bound and the upper bound? For example with Exponential distribution I have to specify the time between two events. And with the uniform distribution?

Comment: There is no flag so that I can move this to compsci.stackexchange.com But I think that would be a more suited place for this type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower and upper bounds specify the range over which the probability is uniform. For example, imagine you go to a bus stop where the bus arrives once every five minutes. If you walk to the bus stop at random times, your wait at the stop will have a lower bound of 0 minutes and an upper bound of 5 minutes. If you were to go to the bus stop 1000 times, and plot the time you waited, you'd see a uniform distribution between 0 and 5 minutes.

Here's how you could make it in python:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
t = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=5, size=1e3)
plt.hist(t, bins=25, color='#75BEBB')
plt.xlabel('Time waiting at bus stop [minutes]')
plt.ylabel('Number of Times')
plt.xlim([-1, 6])
plt.ylim([0, 75])
```

which makes the following plot

[image: Uniform Distribution]

If you're talking probability, you'd want to normalize by the range. Taking the same example as above, normalizing by dividing each bin by 5 (upper - lower bound) would tell us how long we can expect to wait in the future.

[image]

This shows that for any minute, m, between 0 and 5 there's a 20% chance we'll wait for the bus for m minutes, and a 0% chance of waiting for any other length of time.

P(t) = 1/5 for 0 <= t <= 5, else 0

So for your simulation, if you have to specify the time between two events with the uniform distribution, with lower and upper bounds of l and u, respectively, you draw samples from the uniform distribution like so:

```
t = np.random.uniform(low=l, high=u, size=numberSamplesInSimulation)
```

For more details there's [a nice writeup on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)).